# How to set size in rememberAsyncImagePainter in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I am getting image from the url with size. For example size is coming 120x40.

```
@Composable
private fun RowScope.PanelLogo(logo: Logo?) {
    val imageUrl = logo?.url
    val imageWidth = logo?.width!!
    val imageHeight = logo.height!!
    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(imageUrl)
            .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())
            .size(Size(imageWidth, imageHeight))
            .build()
    )
    val isImageValid = !imageUrl.isNullOrEmpty() && painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Success
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = isImageValid) {
        Image(
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = "photo",
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
        )
    }
}
```

I am getting very tiny image and I cannot see properly.

So I am trying to convert 120x40 into dp but it giving me error.

```
val imageWidth = logo?.width?.dp
val imageHeight = logo?.height?.dp
```

[image]

I want to show exact amount of size coming from the server.

**UPDATE**

```
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowScope
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import coil.compose.AsyncImagePainter
import coil.compose.rememberAsyncImagePainter
import coil.decode.SvgDecoder
import coil.request.ImageRequest
import coil.size.Size

@Composable
private fun RowScope.PanelClientLogo(logo: Logo?) {
    val imageUrl = logo?.url
    val imageWidth = logo?.width?.dp
    val imageHeight = logo?.height?.dp
    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(imageUrl)
            .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())
            .size(Size(imageWidth, imageHeight))
            .build()
    )
    val isImageValid = !imageUrl.isNullOrEmpty() && painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Success
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = isImageValid) {
        Image(
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = "photo",
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
        )
    }
}

data class Logo(val url: String? = null, val width: Int? = null, val height: Int? = null)
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowScope
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import coil.compose.AsyncImagePainter
import coil.compose.rememberAsyncImagePainter
import coil.decode.SvgDecoder
import coil.request.ImageRequest

@Composable
private fun RowScope.PanelClientLogo(logo: Logo?) {
    val imageUrl = logo?.url
    val imageWidth = logo?.width?.dp
    val imageHeight = logo?.height?.dp
    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(imageUrl)
            .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())
            .size(coil.size.Size(imageWidth, imageHeight))
            .build()
    )
    val isImageValid = !imageUrl.isNullOrEmpty() && painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Success
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = isImageValid) {
        Image(
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = "photo",
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
        )
    }
}
```

data class Logo(val url: String? = null, val width: Int? = null, val height: Int? = null)

[image]

Comment: Did you use ```Modifier.size()``` for ```Image``` rather setting the ```Size``` from   ```rememberAsyncImagePainter```

Comment: I know we have that but I want in `rememberAsyncImagePainter`.

Answer (score 0):

You import wrong `Size`. It should be `coil.size.Size`. And to pass width and height in Int pixels to Size you can use

```
val imageWidth = logo?.width?.dp?:0.dp
val imageHeight = logo?.height?.dp?:0.dp

val imageWidthPx = LocalDensity.current.run{ imageWidth.roundToPx()}
val imageHeightPx = LocalDensity.current.run{ imageHeight.roundToPx()}

coil.size.Size(imageWidthPx, imageHeightPx)
```

Comment: I already import but it not working. I added full code.

Comment: Change it to size(coil.size.Size(imageWidth, imageHeight) and it should work. You need to assign size from coil library

Comment: Sorry @Thracian still not working. I updated my code..

Comment: You imageWidth and imageHeight params are not nullable, right? I use coil.Size(Int, Int) and Size.ORIGINAL all the time without any problems

Comment: my `imageWidth` and `imageHeight` are nullable value.

Comment: You are passaing nullable dp dimensions as you can see from the image it doesn't accept Dp? Even if you wish to assign dp value you need to convert it to Int or Dimension, i have never used this by the way, to match coil.Size params

Comment: okk got it thanks @Thracian...